# Joomla CHMOD index.php changed from outside

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, hacked

For some time I have had the issue that the file permissions for index.php in the root directory (and sometimes within /administrator folder as well) is automatically changed from 644 and so page access is denied.

Recently, I did walk through all found trouble shootings for Joomla security, did scan website with various online tools, and did setup Admin Tools Pro, but still no results.

Also google search somehow did not deliver any specific results for this issue.

So I just thought I'd try my luck here. How can I prevent the changing chmod for Joomla files from outside.

Comment: Welcome Alex, please take our [tour] and consider introducing yourself in your profile. When posting questions or answers, please do not add a sign-off or "thanks in advance" or "any advice is appreciated" or "hope this helps" or similar in the body of your question -- these implied sentiments must not be written because they do not help researchers. (I am saying this to you so that other members can be aware of good posting behaviours too.)

Comment: Have you tried contacting your hosting provider to see if they can shed any light on the matter?

Comment: I will. i dont see any other option for now. Thanks